# How to get rid of listview and listWidgets flickering?

Tags: c++, listview, qt5, flicker, qlistwidget

I am trying to get the list of processes in a <1 ms intervals and then show the latest list in a `listwidget` or a `listview`.

In the `listWidget` there is a lot of flickering happening. I tried listview it is even worse.

This is my sample code:

```
#include "frmprocess.h"
#include "ui_frmprocess.h"
#include "qprocess.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include "qstring.h"
#include "qtimer.h"
#include "qlist.h"
#include "qmessagebox.h"
 
frmProcess::frmProcess(QWidget *parent) :  QMainWindow(parent),  ui(new Ui::frmProcess)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
 
    //setting timer
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(OnTimerTick()));
 
    model = new QStringListModel(this);
 
}
 
frmProcess::~frmProcess()
{
    delete ui;
}
//in each timer tick event, we get the latest list of running processes
void frmProcess::OnTimerTick()
{
    LatestProcessList.clear();
    LatestProcessList.append(GetAllRunningProcesses());
 
    if(ui->checkBox->isChecked())
    {
        //getting new processes which are not in the white-list
        GetDifference();
    }
   ui->listWidget->addItems(GetAllRunningProcesses());
 
    //Filling model! in order to avoid flickering!-- this doesn't help!
     model->setStringList(LatestProcessList);
     ui->listView->setModel(model);
 
}
 
//This is where we create a white-list of our latest running process list
void frmProcess::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   // GetAllRunningProcesses();
    WhiteList.clear();
    ui->listWidget_2->clear();
 
    WhiteList.append(GetAllRunningProcesses());
    ui->listWidget_2->addItems(WhiteList);
}
//This method gets the list of all running processes
QList<QString> frmProcess::GetAllRunningProcesses()
{
    HANDLE hSysSnapshot = NULL;
    PROCESSENTRY32 proc;
 
    QList<QString> list;
    proc.dwSize = sizeof(proc);
    hSysSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot ( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    Process32First(hSysSnapshot,&proc);
    proc.dwSize = sizeof(proc);
 
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    list.clear();
 
    do
    {
        list.append(QString::fromWCharArray(proc.szExeFile));
    } while(Process32Next(hSysSnapshot,&proc));
 
    CloseHandle( hSysSnapshot );
    return list;
}
 
void frmProcess::GetDifference()
{
   QSet<QString> intersection = LatestProcessList.toSet().subtract(WhiteList.toSet());
   ui->listWidget_3->clear();
   ui->listWidget_3->addItems(intersection.toList());
}
 
void frmProcess::on_btnStartTimer_clicked()
{
    if(ui->btnStartTimer->text()=="Start")
    {
        timer->start(1);
        ui->btnStartTimer->setText("Stop");
    }
    else
    {
        timer->stop();
        ui->btnStartTimer->setText("Start");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to clear and add elements one by one than clearing and adding the whole list at one shot.

Comment: *< 1ms* Interval means *> 1000* Updates per second. Have you thought this through?

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, i chose that since i wanted to get a real-time list.

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but have you seen a display for sale with a refresh rate of 1000 Hz?

Comment: making that to 1 second doesnt solve the problem either! i have a c# counterpart and things are fine, i just dont know what we have in qt to cope with this problem

Comment: 100-250 ms is still real-time as far as human's eye is concerned. You really should lower your refresh rate and see if that alone solves the problem.